Smooth STL not working
New to blender and not sure what I am doing wrong no matter what I do I can not get my stls completely smooth in blender.
I have tried shade smooth, subdivision and nothing seems to get rid of triangles on the model

try to go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

You are referring to smooth shading, yes? Can you show a screenshot, please?

It smooths in blender when I export it for 3d printing it still looks rough. i am not sure how to add a screenshot

hav eyou tried what i suggest?

Yes I did it looks smooth then when I export it and open it in slicer it is still rough looking

Smooth shading is just a way how something is displayed. Really smooth surfaces need a lot of geometry - if your object is too low poly, it will never be really smooth. And I'm quite sure the slicer software does not use any smooth shading, so it does not make the mesh appear smoother than it is.
